# pytest - ModuleNotFoundError - python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, sys

I have a project with this layout:

```
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── company
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── auth.py
│   │   ├── debug.py
│   │   ├── exceptions.py
│   │   ├── reporting.py
│   │   ├── rest.py
│   │   ├── soap.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   ├── jinjaEnvironment.py
│   ├── sql
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── connection.py
│   │   └── sql_helper.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── getUser.xml
│       ├── rest_write_custom_field.xml
│       └── setUser.xml
├── company.egg-info
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_api.py
```

with python -m unittest -v (launched from the project root folder), tests runs fine. 
I tried to install and use pytest, so far without success. As of nwo I tried:

- `pytest`
- `python -m pytest -v`

but I get the same error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/my.user/PycharmProjects/company/tests/test_api.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_api.py:22: in <module>
    from company.api import auth, reporting, exceptions as api_exceptions
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'company.api'
```

I also tried to modify sys.path with:

```
import sys

print(os.path.abspath("."))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
print(sys.path)
```

but I got the same results.
Any help on this?

I'm using python 3.6.4 on OS X 10.13.4

Comment: try adding a .. in front of the import module:
from ..company.api .......

Comment: it works but breaks `python -m unittest`:
`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: more of the traceback available?

Comment: Use `pip install --editable .` and then `pytest` (both from the directory which contains the `setup.py` file).

Comment: @wim same result: `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Comment: @hoefling done. Same error as before.
At the moment I solved it with this nasty thing:
http://dpaste.com/11V5S1M

Comment: Try removing `company.egg-info` dir.

Comment: @hoefling
different exception this time:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Delete the `__init__.py` file from tests subdir, it shouldn't be there.  And wherever you put this `sys.path.insert` garbage, delete all that too.  The correct command is simply `pytest` and the correct import path is `company.api`, as already seen in your traceback.  Make sure `pytest` is installed in the same environment as your package (`'.'`) and you are not accidentally using a pytest installed in the system site-packages.

Comment: You might want to try to set the `PYTHONPATH` like `PYTHONPATH=root_dir pytest ...`

Comment: @wim has the right answer.  Struggled with this for longer than I'd like to admit.